# error variance in ANCOVA vs ANOVA

Tags: self-study, ancova

If for both the treatment and control groups the correlation between the covariate x and the dependent variable y is substantial but negative, the error variance for ANCOVA as compared to ANOVA (less, more or about the same)? I wouldn't think that the direction of the correlation would matter but I am thrown by the wording of the "about the same".  Maybe the error variance between ANOVA and ANCOVA is what I don't understand.

Comment: Is this a question for some subject/course/textbook?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't make sense.  I wouldn't think that the direction would matter regardless of the test you used.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Such questions are welcome but we treat them differently. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), and modify your question as needed - describe your thoughts on the question (start by moving your recent comment up into the question) and do what you can to identify what specific things you need help with.